# Google Contacts API V3, how to search

Tags: google-contacts-api

There are various examples provided in this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users by Google.  However, I can't seem to find what I am looking for.  I want to pull all contacts that include phone numbers or city only.  The search query doesn't seem to support something like `addressStreet:isExists`. Any inputs?

EDIT

When I view Contacts in my GMail, only those I created manually (have phone and address) are displayed. The ones automatically created by GMail (whenever an email is exchanged with someone GMail apparently creates a contact).  When I pull contacts via Google Contacts API v3, I get thousands entries back, most of those are those automatically created ones.

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#ProjectionsAndExtended . It has information about postal address and phone number.

Comment: Yes, but I can't figure out to format a query such as "where phonenumber is not null/empty"

Comment: GMail creates a contact everytime you communicate with an email. Consequently, thousands of contacts exist in Google Contacts per se but a majority of them are not real contacts.  What I am trying to figure out if there is a way to pull only those entries that include something more than just fname, laname and email.

Comment: did you figure out how to filter just the ones you created vs. the auto generated ones?

Comment: @darewreck  yes.  Make a query to groups first and find id of the group that contains "Contacts" in its title.  I think it is "My Contacts".  Then when you search or retrieve for contacts, limit the search to this group id